# Preventing page reload when pressing the 'enter' key

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reload, preventdefault

I've tried reading other questions/answers, but I didn't get it to work.

I tried with this code:

```
function submitClick(e)
{
     e.preventDefault();
     otherFunction();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactSend').click(submitClick(e));
});
```

But tells me that 'e' is not defined in `$('#contactSend').click(submitClick(e));`

The website is `http://207.45.189.68:8004`, the javascript is http://bluecodestudio.com/scripts/kiposgift.js, which at the very bottom has some commented out code I was trying to solve out the problem.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it to work. The onSubmit event doesn't come from the  object, but from the  object. Facepalm...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that your callback `submitClick` is being called immediately, instead of being passed as an argument to `click`.

Try this instead:

```
$(doucment).ready(function() {
  $('#contactSend').click(submitClick);
});
```